# How to add dynamic element jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have this html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Agenda</title>
  <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/agenda.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src=js/agenda.js></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 ">
                <input type="text" id="txtNombre"  placeholder="Usuario" required="" autofocus="" class="form-control" >
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 ">
                <input type="text" id="txtTelefono"  placeholder="Telefono" required="" autofocus="" class="form-control" >
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 ">
                <input type="text" id="txtDireccion"  placeholder="Direccion" required="" autofocus="" class="form-control" >
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 ">
                <input type="text" id="txtEmail"  placeholder="Correo" required="" autofocus="" class="form-control" >
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12  col-md-3  col-md-offset-9 ">
            <img src="img/mas.png" class="agregar" id="btnAgregar" autofocus="" >
        </div>  
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

When user press "add" it must to add a new row with  same date in the inputs,
but add to every row the button for, edit the current row and delete it.
so you can add N element and delete Row by Row (or edit it one by one).

I am working with jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi please check this link

```
https://plnkr.co/edit/B2Nmf5wzKBqHypnLFc59
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
   <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row main" id="main">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 ">
                <input type="text" id="txtNombre"  placeholder="Usuario" required="" autofocus="" class="form-control" >
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 ">
                <input type="text" id="txtTelefono"  placeholder="Telefono" required="" autofocus="" class="form-control" >
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 ">
                <input type="text" id="txtDireccion"  placeholder="Direccion" required="" autofocus="" class="form-control" >
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 ">
                <input type="text" id="txtEmail"  placeholder="Correo" required="" autofocus="" class="form-control" >
        </div>
    </div>   
    <div class="row buttonbox">
        <div class="col-xs-12  col-md-3  col-md-offset-9 ">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success add" >ADD +</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove" >DEL -</button>
        </div>  
    </div>

</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

and JS

```
// Add your javascript here
$(function(){
   var i = 0;
  var last12 = $('.buttonbox').last();
  $(document).on('click', '.add', function() {

  var clone = $('#main').clone();
 clone.find("input").val("");
 clone.attr("id", "main" + i++).insertBefore(last12);



      //clone.id = "main" + i;

  });

  $(".remove").click(function(){

     $('.main:last').remove();
  });
});
```

you can clone the above div and add again

Answer (score 0):

Update your HTML by adding 2 button add and subtract of rows,

HTML

```
<div class="row">
 <!--For adding row-->
<div class="col-xs-12  col-md-3  col-md-offset-9 ">
    <img src="#" class="agregar" id="btnadd" autofocus="" >
</div>  
<!-- for removing rows-->      
    <div class="col-xs-12  col-md-3  col-md-offset-9 ">
        <img src="#" class="agregar" id="btnrmv" autofocus="" >
    </div>
```

Updated JS,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btnadd").click(function(){
$(".container > .row:first").clone().insertBefore('.row:last');
});
$("#btnrmv").click(function(){
$(".row:first").remove();
});
});
```

Thus every-time when user clicks #btnadd it adds one and onclick #btnrmv it remove one.